# .call() is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have made a CSS3 animation plugin for jquery that works perfectly in JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/backflip/BqFsM/

but when i use it in my context i get "TypeError: Result of expression '$fnStop.call' [undefined] is not a function."

here is my code: http://meodai.ch/alainbenoit/

but i can't figure out why. Any idea?

This is how i overwrite the jquery native Stop function:

```
if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    $fnStop = $.fn.stop();
    $.fn.stop = function(clearQueue, jumpToEnd) {
        if (this.data("css3animate")) {
            return methods.stop.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            return $fnStop.call(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fnStop = $.fn.stop();
```

Should probably be:

```
$fnStop = $.fn.stop;
```

You probably want to point to it, not *trigger* it (and save its result).

Comment: wow thank you, that was fast. But any idea, why does it work in jsFiddle then?

Comment: @meo - excellent question. I'm not sure. I was just looking into that, but it's quite a lot of code...